# How to perform blind search within excel work book using c#

Tags: c#, excel, .net-3.5

I am importing excel file into `datagridview` then after that I want to perform blind search within these data which maybe imported from one or more file

for now I am filtering data using method below that I am calling it on the `Texrbox_TextChanged` event

```
public void DataFilter()
{
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = DGV_Data.DataSource;


    bs.Filter = string.Format(@"convert(National_ID,'System.String') LIKE '%{0}%' 
                                    AND First_Name LIKE '%{1}%' 
                                    AND Father_Name LIKE '%{2}%' 
                                    AND Last_Name LIKE '%{3}%' 
                                    AND Mother_Full_Name LIKE '%{4}%' 
                                   AND Nationality LIKE '%{5}%'",
                                    TB_National_ID.Text,
                                    TB_First_Name.Text,
                                    TB_Father_Name.Text,
                                    TB_Last_Name.Text,
                                    TB_Mother_Full_Name.Text,
                                    TB_Nationality.Text);

    DGV_Data.DataSource = bs;
    Re-calculate record counts

L_Rows_Count.Text = "Count: " + (DGV_Data.Rows.Count - 1).ToString("n0");
}
```

but that will filter data based on the column, so i tried to convert it to blind search as below

```
public void DataFilter()
{
    ExcelRange.get_Range("A1", "XFD1");

    Range findRng = 
    ExcelRange.Find("hello sa", 
                    Type.Missing,
                    Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas, 
                    Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, 
                    Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                    Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, 
                    false, 
                    false, 
                    false);

    DGV_Data.DataSource = bs;
    Re-calculate record counts

L_Rows_Count.Text = "Count: " + (DGV_Data.Rows.Count - 1).ToString("n0");
}
```

I am getting error that says

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

also that will not give back to `datagridview` all records that may match the text ... I will lose the LIKE functionality

and I don't won't to use ranges cause my code will not be fixable

also any suggestion or better ideas ?

**UPDATE**

I don't know if that possible to use a sample query with where clause in somehow

```
cmdtxt = @"select * from [" + ExcelWorkSheets.Name + "$] where somehow ";
```